# localization(i18n) in sapui5 for fragment.xml file in not appearing

Tags: localization, sapui5

I have a button (create Application) if i click on  a button a fragmented dialog will be appearing . here am able to show fragmented dialog .but internalization(i18n) is not appearing for the fields. (For `xml` files able to show `i18n` but for `fragment.xml` file not able to show `i18n`/)

`component.js`:

```js
createContent : function() {

        // create root view
        var oView = sap.ui.view({
            id : "app",
            viewName : "sap.gss.program.view.App",
            type : "JS",
            viewData : { component : this }
        });

        var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
            bundleUrl : "i18n/appTexts_fr.properties"
            });

        oView.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");      
        return oView;
    }
```

`Controller.js`:

```js
createApplication: function (oEvent) {

    if (!this.oDialogFragment) {
         this.oDialogFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment("sap.gss.program.view.myFragment",
                                                   this);       
    }        
    this.oDialogFragment.open(); 

}
```

`fragment.xml`:

```html
<core:FragmentDefinition
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1">
  <Dialog
    title="{i18n>Title}"
    class="sapUiPopupWithPadding" >   
    <HBox> 
      <Text  text="{i18n>Description_TEXT}" > </Text>       
    </HBox>  
    <beginButton>
      <Button text="{i18n>Ok}"  press="DialogButton" />
    </beginButton>
    <endButton>
      <Button text="{i18n>Cancel}"  press="CloseButton" />
    </endButton>
  </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should set the i18n resource model for the dialog fragment as well.

```js
createApplication: function(oEvent) {

    if (!this.oDialogFragment) {

        this.oDialogFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment("sap.gss.program.view.myFragment", this);     
        var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
                            bundleUrl : "i18n/appTexts_fr.properties"
                        });
        this.oDialogFragment.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");      

    }

   this.oDialogFragment.open();
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `dependents` aggregation, to connect up the dialog to the view; you don't need to set any models explicitly.

So in your case you would do this:

```js
createApplication: function (oEvent) {
    if (!this.oDialogFragment) {
        this.oDialogFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment("sap.gss.program.view.myFragment", this);
    }
    this.getView().addDependent(oDialogFragment); // <--
    this.oDialogFragment.open();
}
```

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24640317/384366) to '[What is the usage of "dependents" aggregation in SAPUI5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24633596/what-is-the-usage-of-dependents-aggregation-in-sapui5)' for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Its often the easiest way esp. for a `ResourceModel` to just set it globally:

`sap.ui.getCore().setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");`

Now you can reference it from everywhere in your application and bind to it like you did, no need to ever set it again on view- or even control-level.

Comment: When you work in the Fiori Launchpad, you should NOT do this as it conflicts with other apps.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, so setup model in Component globally and locally. It is working correctly.

```js
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
this.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
```

Comment: This is fine as long as there are no Components involved. Otherwise, please avoid setting models on the Core. More: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251431/