# Global Model Not Accesible

Tags: sapui5

I declared a model in *Component.js* of a UI5 application as below

```js
init: function() {
  sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this);
  var oModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/mock.json");
  sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel1, "oModelForSales");
},
```

but was not able to access the model in any of the `onInit` methods inside controllers unless the model is set on view instead as below:

```js
var oModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/routes.json");
this.getView().setModel(oModel1);
```

The log for `sap.ui.getCore().getModel("oModelForSales")` in controllers `onInit` shows the model as `undefined` but I was able to fetch it in `onBeforeRendering` handler.

Why are core models, set in *Component.js*, not accessible in `onInit`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

can you once try this code -

```
init:function(){
        //sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this);
        var oModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/mock.json");
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel1,"oModelForSales");
        console.log(sap.ui.getCore().getModel("oModelForSales"));
        sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this);
    },
```

and then in you init method of any controller try -

```
console.log(sap.ui.getCore().getModel("oModelForSales"));
```

I think  sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this);->calls the create content methods and your view and controllers are initialised even before your model is defined, hence you get undefined as model. Using my approach, we create the model first and then call the super init method in Component.

Note @Admins-> I dont have enough points to comment, so adding an answer.

Comment: you should not register models globally in the core, because it can be overwritter from thirdparty code you have not under control

Answer (score 19):

Avoid setting models on the Core directly if you're using Components. Components are meant to be independent and reusable parts and therefore will **not** inherit the Core models *by default*. Models should be set depending on your business case:

- Models declared in the [*app descriptor* (`manifest.json`) section `/sap.ui5/models`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html#loiobe0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da/section_sap_ui5) will be set on the Component. They are automatically propagated to its descendants. Given default model, the following returns true:

  ```js
  this.getOwnerComponent().getModel() === this.getView().getModel() // returns: true
  ```

  **Note:** calling `this.getView().getModel()` in `onInit` [will **still return `undefined`**](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/790) since the view doesn't know its parent [at that moment](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/d2f58695fce3476f92fdfc07c9e8f7c6) yet (`this.getView().getParent()` returns `null`). Therefore, in `onInit`, call the `getModel` explicitly from the parent that owns the model. E.g.:

  ```js
  { // My.controller.js
    onInit: function {
      // The view is instantiated but no parent is assigned yet.
      // Models from the parent aren't accessible here.
      // Accessing the model explicitly from the Component works:
      const myGlobalModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel(/*modelName*/);
    },
  }
  ```
- Set models only on certain controls (e.g. View, Panel, etc.) if the data are not needed elsewhere.
- Set models on the Core only if the app is **not** Component-based.

If Core models or any other model from upper hierarchy should still be propagated to the Component and its children, enable [`propagateModel`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer#methods/setPropagateModel) when instantiating the ComponentContainer.

```js
new ComponentContainer({ // required from "sap/ui/core/ComponentContainer"
  //...,
  propagateModel: true // Allow propagating parent binding and model information (e.g. from the Core) to the Component and it's children.
})
```

But again, this is not a good practice since Core models can be blindly overwritten by other apps on FLP as [SAP recommends](https://help.sap.com/viewer/a7b390faab1140c087b8926571e942b7/latest/en-US/88681e71e3584497908a30767d28ac78.html):

> Do **not** use `sap.ui.getCore()` to register models.

---

About the Core model being undefined in `onInit`: This is not the case anymore as of version 1.34.0. The Core model can be accessed from anywhere in the controller. However, descendants of `ComponentContainer` are unaware of such models by default as explained above.

Answer (score 1):

You should not set the Model to the Core.

Instead set it to the Component. That way the Controllers and Views belonging to that Component will be able to access it.

Comment: Hi i got it , so when we set a model to a component in init function like below  init : function() {
var workModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/workModel.json");
  this.setModel(workModel, "workModel");
  sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
 }
how can we access the above "workmodel" for all the other controllers and view belonged to it

Comment: So a Model in  Component.js can be directly accessed with out setting the model explicitly to view ? but the above given line is logging as undefined in console.log in a controller init method.

Comment: Make sure to use the same name for the model when setting and getting it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding more info on this:

During `onInint` of a controller, the view/controllers do not know their parent as where would they land, and hence they can not refer to the model.

However, this can be achieved from the following code:

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel()
```

As the component is already initialized and should return the model.