# Issues with scope of "this." object reference: Can't access model in onInit

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have issues understanding the change of the `this` reference in my code. So there are three things I don't get:

1. When I try to get my model in the `onInit`, I get:

   > "Cannot read property 'getProperty' of undefined".

   But I can access the model of my view within the XML view since I defined the model in my *manifest.json* and use the manifest in my app Component. Why can't I access the model in the controller via `this.getView().getModel`?
2. In my `onDetailRouteHit` method, I can get the model perfectly fine with `this.getView().getModel`.
3. When I call the `_Test` method, I get this error again:

   > "Cannot read property 'getProperty' of undefined"

So why can't I access the model in the `onInit` but in the `onDetailRouteHit`? And why can I access it in the `onDetailRouteHit` but not in the function I call after that? I'm used to Java where the `this` references the current object what I assume to be the controller I'm currently in in my example.

Are there "rules" of the `this` scope in JS / UI5?

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("test.controller.Detail", {
    onInit: function() {
      var array1 = this.getView().getModel("myData").getProperty("/myDataSet");
      this.oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
      this.oRouter.getRoute("detail").attachPatternMatched(this._onDetailRouteHit.bind(this));
    },

    _onDetailRouteHit: function(oEvent) {
      var array2 = this.getView().getModel("myData").getProperty("/myDataSet");
      this._Test();
    },

    _Test: function() {
      var array3 = this.getView().getModel("myData").getProperty("/myDataSet");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.getView().getModel("myData")` returns `undefined` in onInit is because the view isn't associated with the parent at that moment. Take a look at [this graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yukIT.png) from the documentation. It says:

> Init function of controller is executed --> Router places views in root control: models are now available within the view and its controller.

If you want to access the model in onInit from higher hierarchy (e.g. Component model), you need to get the reference of that model owner explicitly and then call `getModel` from it: `this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("myData")`

→ [More about model propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251431/5846045)

Answer (score -1):

check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). It explains **this**.

So basically it can have a different meaning based on you object and scope.

Now on to the 3 functions.

- in the onInit, your view has not been instantiated yet, so this.getView() returns null

in your second met the view has been instantiated and this is a direct link to your controller. Hence it get a return object which is your view because your controller can access it's view.

Your last case surprises me because i would have expected that function to be able to get to the view. If it doesn't should compare the "this" object in the debugger and see what it's reference is.

Comment: Thanks! I found something similar here: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/790