# Set the value of a global variable in a function

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm currently working on an [SAP Fiori app](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/03265b0408e2432c9571d6b3feb6b1fd.html) that consumes an OData service.

I created a method in my controller `fonct` that calculates a variable coming from my OData.

I want to capture this value and put it in a global variable every time the view is refreshed.

I created a global variable like this:

```
var boo1;
return Controller.extend("com.controller.Detail", {...});
```

and I passed `boo1` as a parameter in my method `fonct` inside my `onInit` method but it is `undefined`.

Here's a snippet of my controller's code:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "com/util/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
    "use strict";

    var boo1;
    return Controller.extend("com.controller.Detail", {
        onInit: function() {
            this.fonct(boo1);
            alert(boo1);
        },          

        fonct: function(ovar) {
            var that = this;
            var oModel = that.getView().getModel();
            oModel.read("/alertSet", {
                success: function(data) {
                    var a = JSON.stringify(data);
                    var b = a.slice(332,-4);
                    ovar = b;
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should declare the global variable at global scope (i.e., before `sap.ui.define`).

Comment: Declaring variables at that scope is especially dangerous in SAPUI5 and Fiori Launchpad due to the high risk of unintended naming collisions. Defining anything before `sap.ui.define` should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want to do is simplier that what you are doing.
To save a global variable, get the Core object and set the variable as a new property of this object:

sap.ui.getCore()**.myGlobalVar** = myCalculatedValue;

Then to use it in other view, get the property directly from the Core:

var mySavedVar = sap.ui.getCore()**.myGlobalVar**

Then use the Router routeMatched event to handle your navigation and refresh the value.

Here a snippet: https://jsbin.com/bewigusopo/edit?html,output

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' >
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >
    <title>test</title>

    <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
            src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.5/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
        data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
        data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"></script>

    <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
        <mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
            <core:ComponentContainer name='my.comp'/>
        </mvc:View>
    </script>

    <script id="home" type="sapui5/xmlview">
        <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
            controllerName="my.controller1">
            <Page>
                <Input id="input" placeholder="Write a text to save it globally"/>
                <Button text="Navigate to other view" press="onNavigate"/>
            </Page>
        </mvc:View>
    </script>

    <script id="add" type="sapui5/xmlview">
        <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
            controllerName="my.controller2">
            <Page id="page" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onBack">
              <HBox class="sapUiLargeMarginBegin">
                 <Label text="The global variable is:" class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd sapUiSmallMarginTop"/>
                 <Input id="inputResult"/>
              </HBox>
            </Page>
        </mvc:View>
    </script>

    <script>
        // jQuery.sap.declare("my.comp.Component");
        sap.ui.define("my/comp/Component", ["sap/ui/core/UIComponent"], function(UIComponent) {
            return UIComponent.extend("my.comp.Component", {
                metadata : {
                    name : "GreatComponent",
                    version : "1.0",
                    includes : [],
                    dependencies : {
                        libs : ["sap.m"]
                    },
                    routing: {
                        config: {
                            routerClass: "sap.m.routing.Router",
                            viewType: "XML",
                            viewPath: "my",
                            controlId: "app",
                            transition: "slide",
                            controlAggregation: "pages"
                        },
                        routes: [
                            {
                                name: "home",
                                pattern: "",
                                target: "home"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "add",
                                pattern: "add",
                                target: "add"
                            }
                        ],
                        targets: {
                            home: {
                                viewName: "Home",
                                title: "home"
                            },
                            add: {
                                viewName: "Add",
                                title: "add"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                init: function() {
                    sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
                    var oRouter = this.getRouter();
                    var oViews = oRouter.getViews();
                    this.runAsOwner(function() {
                        var myHome = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#home').html()});
                        oViews.setView("my.Home", myHome);
                        var myAdd = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#add').html()});
                        oViews.setView("my.Add", myAdd);
                    });
                    oRouter.initialize();
                },
                createContent : function() {
                    var componentData = this.getComponentData();
                    return new sap.m.App("app", {
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        sap.ui.define("my/controller1", [
          "sap/ui/core/UIComponent"
        ],function(UIComponent) {
            return sap.ui.controller("my.controller1", {
                onInit: function() {
                    this.oRouter = UIComponent.getRouterFor(this.getView());
                },

                onNavigate: function() {
                    var sInputText = this.getView().byId("input").getValue();
                    sap.ui.getCore().myGlobalVar = sInputText;     
                    console.log(sap.ui.getCore().myGlobalVar)

                    this.oRouter.navTo("add");
                }
            });
        });

        sap.ui.define("my/controller2", [
          "sap/ui/core/UIComponent"
        ],function(UIComponent) {
            return sap.ui.controller("my.controller2", {
                onInit: function() {
                    this.oRouter = UIComponent.getRouterFor(this.getView());

                    this.oRouter.getRoute("add").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
                },

                _onObjectMatched: function(){
                    var sGlobalVariable = sap.ui.getCore().myGlobalVar;
                    console.log(sGlobalVariable);
                    this.getView().byId("inputResult").setValue(sGlobalVariable);
                },

                onBack: function(){
                    this.oRouter.navTo("home");
                }
            });
        });
        sap.ui.require(["my/comp/Component"], function(myComp) {
            // instantiate the View
            sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()}).placeAt('content');
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body class='sapUiBody'>
    <div id='content'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Other possibility is to set a global model, which will simplyfy your binding very much. Just create it and set it into the Core

```
//To set it
var oGlobalModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oGlobalModel, "myGlobalModelID");

//To get it
var oMyGlobalModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("myGlobalModelID");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, **avoid defining global variables** (such as before `sap.ui.define`) especially if you are working on apps that are going to be placed into the Fiori Launchpad. This approach is [considered harmful](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad). This is also repeated in the documentation:

> In control and class modules, you should **not** use global variables at all.[<sup>(src)</sup>](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/c78c07c094e04ccfaab659378a1707c7)

We're using `"use strict"` purposely to disallow such practices.

Also, defining properties or adding models on `sap.ui.getCore()` is an anti-pattern for Fiori apps. Not only does this lead to the same flaws as defining global variables but models set on the core [are not propagated to the views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251431/5846045) *by default* because components are meant to be used modularly. Therefore, defining such data to the corresponding **component instead of the core** is the way to go for Fiori apps.

==> **[FLP Best Practices](https://help.sap.com/viewer/a7b390faab1140c087b8926571e942b7/latest/en-US/88681e71e3584497908a30767d28ac78.html)**

---

> I created a global variable
>
> ```
> var boo1;
> return Controller.extend("com.controller.Detail", {...});
> ```

What you created though was not a *global variable* since `boo1` was declared inside an anonymous function. Instead, `boo1` was stored in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) which allowed the prototype methods (`onInit` and `fonc`) to maintain the lexical environment within which `boo1` was made accessible not only by the methods but also by other instances of `com.controller.Detail`. In terms of Java, we can say that `boo1` is a private static variable. But it's not a global variable.

That being said..

> I passed `boo1` as a parameter in my method `fonct` inside my `onInit` method but it is `undefined`

The closure makes passing `boo1` as an argument unnecessary (unless you want a hard copy of `boo1` to maintain multiple states of it). The method `fonct` can access `boo1` directly, even in the anonymous callbacks defined in `fonct`.

Now, you may be asking why `boo1` was `undefined`. There are two reasons:

1. `boo1` was `undefined` before calling `fonct`. If `boo1` were an object instead of undefined, then `ovar` would have been a reference to the `boo1` object and the change to any `ovar` property would have took place in the `boo1` object. But `undefined` is not an object. So `ovar` doesn't know what `boo1` is at all. **Note:** The evaluation strategy of JS is "[Call by object-sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)".
2. `alert(boo1)` gets fired right after calling `fonct`. Unless `oModel` works synchronously (which I strongly recommend **not** to do so), the browser doesn't wait for the success callback to get fired in order to invoke `alert(boo1)` later. The alert is fired immediately, and then the success callback where `boo1` should be manipulated.

Removing `ovar` and using `boo1` instead updates `boo1` properly in the success callback.

```
fonct: function(/*no ovar*/) {
    //...
    oModel.read("/alertSet", {
        success: function(data) {
            //...
            boo1 = /*new value*/;
            alert(boo1);
        }.bind(this)
    });
}
```