# how to create global variables in ui5?

Tags: sapui5, rich-text-editor

I am trying to make a rich text editor a global variable using the window in UI5 but I keep getting the error "ui5 definition of global variable/api in window object is not permitted (`sap-no-global-define`)". My code looks something like this

```
window.oRichTextEditor = new RichTextEditor("myRTE", {
    editorType: sap.ui.richtexteditor.EditorType.TinyMCE4,
    width: "100%",
    height: "600px",
    customToolbar: true,
    showGroupFont: true,
    showGroupLink: true,
    showGroupInsert: true,
    value: data,
    ready: function () {
        this.addButtonGroup("styleselect").addButtonGroup("table");
    }
```

I was wondering why isn't this working? Could some explain the error to me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set the value of a global variable in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709170/set-the-value-of-a-global-variable-in-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

First, [UI5 strictly recommends](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/eded636b85584cd586b1fe231d2b5dac), not using globals!

If you **really** need globals, you can use ObjectPath.set()

```
sap.ui.require(["sap/base/util/ObjectPath"], function (ObjectPath) {
      ObjectPath.set(["oRichTextEditor"], "I_Know_What_I_Am Doing!");
});
```