# Control with bound property doesn't display model data in the UI

Tags: sapui5

I'm migrating my app to new version of OpenUI5 (1.48) and have some problems with model bindings. I am using `sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "myModel")` for model declaration and when I'm trying to bind some controls to values from this model like this ...

```xml
<Text text="{local>/count}" />
```

... the value isn't displayed.

But if I get this model, set it to view in controller ...

```js
var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("local");
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

```xml
<Text text="{/count}" />
```

... everything would work fine.
Maybe somebody faced a similar problem or has an idea what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using a `Component` in your app. In that case, core models are not automatically propagated to the children of the `ComponentContainer` which is why your `Text` control doesn't know the model `"local"`.

The reason why `"{/count}"` works is because you set the model explicitly on the view without any model name. If the model doesn't have a name, it's a default model and `>` has to be omitted in the binding path.

To learn more about where to set models, take a look at my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251431/5846045

Answer (score 1):

I think problem may be how you creating the **JSON model!**,

try this one.
**Controller**

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
               "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",],
               function(Controller,JSONModel) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("com.stackoverflow.testUI5", {

        onInit:function(){

            var oData = {
                    count:"1"
            };
        var oModel = new JSONModel(oData);
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel , "local")
            //this.getView().setModel(oModel ,"local");

        }
});
});
```

**XML View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<mvc:View controllerName="com.stackoverflow.testUI5"
     xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"  xmlns="sap.m" >

            <Text text="{local>/count}"/>

</mvc:View>
```

this snippet will work.

Comment: Please, don't recommend to set the model on the **core**. This is an unfortunate anti-pattern which should've been avoided from the beginning.