# How to apply global model in XML View?

Tags: xml, sapui5

I am trying to define a global model in one of my controllers and then trying to get its value in some XML Views but I don't know why it doesn't show up.

Controller :

```js
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModelo, "miModelo");
```

View :

```xml
<Text id="selectiona"
  class="selectiona"
  text="{= ${miModelo>/miSelectiona}.length > 0 ? 'Selected:' + ${miModelo>/miSelectiona} : ''}"
/>
```

P.S: it works when I s set the model like this:

```js
this.byId("selectiona").setModel(oModelo,"miModelo");
```

But I need to define it globally. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251431/5846045), models set on the `Core` are not propagated to the children of the `ComponentContainer`. Therefore, set the model on the `Component` instead. You can do this either declaratively in *manifest.json* or by calling `this.setModel(...)` in *Component.js*. Then, the model will be propagated automatically to its children, meaning the view will be able to display the model data without any involvement of any controller. If required, you can still access the model from the any controller by calling `this.getOwnerComponent().getModel(...)`.

Examples:

- https://embed.plnkr.co/S7mIArBu2mIesmVa?show=Component.js,view%2FHome.view.xml,preview
- [Sample](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.10/code/webapp%2FComponent.js) from [*Walkthrough Step 10*](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/8f93bf2b2b13402e9f035128ce8b495f).

Answer (score 0):

Declare it on manifest.json. Here is an example:

```
"models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "atendimentoMobile.i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "viewModel": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
            "dataSource": "viewModelDs",
            "settings": {
                "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay"
            }
        },
        "deviceModel": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
            "dataSource": "deviceDs",
            "settings": {
                "defaultBindingMode": "OneWay"
            }
        },
        "authModel": {
            "dataSource": "authServiceDs",
            "settings": {
                "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
                "useBatch": false
            }
        },
        "chamadosModelOdata": {
            "dataSource": "mainServiceDs",
            "settings": {
                "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
                "useBatch": false
            }
        }
    }
```